# python plot - index strings broken

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

when i plot a graph in python the column string was broken in jupyter.

```
lambdalist = [600, 300, 150, 75, 37.5, 18.75, 9.375, 4.6875]#, 2.34375, 1.171875]
data = np.array(w_check[3].tolist() + w_check[13].tolist()+ w_check[39].tolist()+ w_check[45].tolist()+ w_check[66].tolist()).T.tolist()

wchanges = pd.DataFrame(data, index=lambdalist, columns=['', '', '', '', ''])

wchanges.plot()
```

and the result is

[image]

how can i print that squared things properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names contain monospace letters. If this is intentional, you may want to change the matplotlib font family to monospace:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'
```